# Why can't pointer to pointer, access struct members without a cast?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-precedence, unary-operator

In C++, I was trying to access the struct members through double pointer `headref` as shown below

```
struct Node{
    int data; 
    struct Node* next; 
};

struct Node* head = new Node;
head->data = 10; 
head->next = NULL; 

struct Node** headref = &head;
```

However, accessing as `*headref->data` produces errors while casting it `((Node*)*headref)->data` works. Why?

Comment: Can you include the error in your question?

Comment: What kind of errors are you facing?

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Note that `->` has higher precedence than `*`

Comment: It's not the cast. If you think it's the cast, try `((Node*)headref)->data` instead of `((Node*)*headref)->data`. It should fail spectacularly. The cast as you wrote it is a no-op.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks. Precedence was the issue.

Comment: @SiddhantChhabra Bookmark that site. It's like a holy grail for c++ and c developers alike.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This expression

```
*headref->data
```

is equivalent to

```
*( headref->data )
```

It is not the same as the valid expression

```
( *headref )->data
```

because the data member `data` has no pointer type and you may not apply the unary operator * to it.

This expression

```
((Node*)*headref)->data
```

is valid not due to the casting. It is valid because if to remove the casting that is redundant you will get the valid edxpression

```
( /*(Node*)*/ *headref)->data
```

shown above.

Comment: Ah this solved it. Thanks. I'll go through the operator precedence.

Answer (score 3):

If you chain operators together, it's always a good idea to make sure you remember their precedence correctly. As listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator->` has a higher precedence than the indirection `*`. Hence

```
*headref->data
```

is interpreted as

```
*(headref->data)
```

which can't work. Instead, use

```
(*headref)->data
```

which is equivalent to `((Node*)headref)->data`.